# Как изучать winsock2.h ?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте !

Есть цель изучить эту библиотеку, но книг по ней не нашел. Нагуглил всякие обрывки и нашел только один путевый FAQ, но на английском...

Подскажите, где найти наиболее исчерпывающий материал для изучения ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такая книга "Эффективное программирование TCP/IP" ISBN: 5-318-00453-9, 0-201-61589-4. Наиполнейшее собрание советов и рекомендаций в работе с сокетами в Unix и Windows.

Comment: Хорошая книга Иона Снайдера, написал по ней свой ftp-клиент на TCL/TK =)

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, лучшим путем изучения данной библиотеки будет написание простого клиента и сервера сначала на обычных сокетах, потом на асинхронных.

Answer (score 2):

В журнале MSDN есть хорошая статья на русском: [WinSock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd335942.aspx), правда там .NET. И еще много [на английском](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms740673.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

"Самоучитель игры на WINSOCK", Крис Касперски.

Answer (score 1):

"UNIX. Разработка сетевых приложений", У. Р. Стивенс, Б. Феннер, Э. М. Рудофф. - Книжка про юникс, но в данном случае там много общего.